# Oracle - EXCEPT Error

Tags: oracle, select, except

Have few columns and tables, as follows:

**NOTE**: The names of elements used are for illustrative purposes only.

```
SELECT T.col1 
FROM Table1 T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   (SELECT * FROM Table2) 
     EXCEPT (SELECT TT.col1 
             FROM TableTT TT 
             WHERE TT.col2 = T.col2)
     );
```

**Error: Missing right parenthesis**, though the parentheses seem to match.

But, I do know that it has nothing to do with the parenthesis actually. And I suspect the error to be somewhere in the **EXCEPT** clause. What might have resulted in the error?

Comment: Sergey is correct, you need to use minus. I think you've confused what you're doing though. `not exists` needs to linked to an identifier of some description otherwise it'll always return true if the table in that sub-query is not empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no `EXCEPT` operator in Oracle. Use `MINUS` instead. Reference: [Here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-nonstandard.html)

In your query the word 'EXCEPT' is most probably treated as a table alias for `(SELECT * FROM Table2)` subquery.

**UPDATE:**

Full query for provided data structure will look like:

```
SELECT T.col1 
FROM Table1 T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
((SELECT col1 FROM Table2) 
MINUS 
(SELECT TT.col1 FROM TableTT TT WHERE TT.col2 = T.col2));
```

Note that I have changed `*` to `col1` for `Table2` - if you're selecting single INT column `TT.col1` from `TT` then you should also select single INT column from `Table2`.

Comment: Tried that earlier. But had two errors. i) Incorrect number of result columns. Hence removed * from the last sub query so that the no. of cols match. ii) After i) the corresponding data types seem to mismatch.

Comment: Could you provide your table structures then?

Comment: Sorry power cut.

Table T - col1 INT, col2 CHAR, col3 VARCHAR
Table 2 - col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR  col3 CHAR
Table TT - col1 INT - col1 from Table 2
col2 INT - col2 from Table T
col3 INT

Comment: Then you can't use EXCEPT/MINUS like this - when using this construct left and right sides should have exactly the same structure. Will write a full query in a minute.